# Xcode reporting duplicate symbol error when linking a SINGLE framework static library

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-linking, duplicate-symbol

When linking a particular iOS app project to a static framework, Xcode is reporting duplicate symbol errors from within the ***single*** static framework file (although the duplicates are reported sourced from different object files within that framework):

```
duplicate symbol _kMGLMinimalViewport in:
/Users/alex/Documents/Code/MyProject/ThirdParty/MetalGL-0.9.0/MetalGL/MetalGL.framework/MetalGL(MGLContext.o)
/Users/alex/Documents/Code/MyProject/ThirdParty/MetalGL-0.9.0/MetalGL/MetalGL.framework/MetalGL(MGLRenderPipelineState.o)
```

The `_kMGLMinimalViewport` symbol being reported as duplicate is a struct that is declared and defined within a header file within the source code of the framework:

```
MGLPixelRect kMGLMinimalViewport = (MGLPixelRect){0, 0, 0, 0};
```

which is then `#import`ed into several implementation files within the framework source, including both `.m` files and inline functions within other `.h` files. The symbol is used strictly internally within the framework and the declaration is not even visible to the final app project as part of a visible header file.

Confusingly, this duplicate error does not appear when linking this framework to other app projects, but I can't find any reason why this particular app project is reporting an error when linking this framework.

Comment: Bil how do u import it ? What the difference between the other apps and this specific app? did u try to remove and import it again ? clean (delete the derived data also) and import it again .(import it to one target at first step).

Comment: It turns out the "app" that was causing this issue was actually a dynamic framework that was linking to our pre-compiled static framework. I fixed the issue by  hiding all non-public symbols within the static framework. This was done by marking the publicly exposed symbols with __attribute__((visibility("default"))), and then using the GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN compiler setting to hide everything else.

Comment: Hi Bill. I also have such kind of problem with duplicate symbol with MetalGL. Could you please provide more detailed answer how to fix it. We're very interested in MetalGL, but for now we can't build the project. I tried to set GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN to Yes.

Comment: FIX IT! by removing "all_load" from "Other Linker Flags" in build settings